# Python how to use assert with function that make modification in place?

Tags: python

Let's assume I want to create a function that multiplies every element of a list by 2. Once this function is created I want to check that everything works by verifying that `[1, 2]` becomes `[2, 4]`. If my function creates a new list, I can do this in the following way :

```
def double(l):
    new_l = []
    for j in l:
        new_l.append(j * 2)
    return new_l
```

and

```
assert double([1, 2]) == [2, 4]
```

Now, if my function modifies the list in place like :

```
def double(l):
    for i, j in enumerate(l):
        l[i] = j * 2
```

I can do

```
l = [1, 2]
double(l)
assert l == [2, 4]
```

I find this solution not very elegant. Is there a way to do this in a one liner, or a better way to do this?

Comment: I think that in the last block, you mean `assert l == [ 3, 4]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to do it. If the function modifies something *without* returning it, what you have done is the only option.

You *could* both modify it and return it, in your second function (that is, add `return l` in the last line). However, it's misleading, because when someone writes `y = f(x)` he doesn't expect `x` to change. In general, a function should *either do something, or return something, not both*.

The better way is to keep your first form, as it is easy to test and has no side effects.